# find an element by an id and hide the previous div

Tags: jquery

Perhaps a simple question but I can't figure this one out.

What I try to do is to find an id which is placed within a div. When found I want to add an extra class name to the previous div. The problem is that the only id is placed within a div.

HTML

```
<div class="radio"> // to this class I want to add an extra class like "hide"
   <input type="radio" id="invoice-method"> 
   <label for="invoice-method">.....</label>
</div>
```

So I need to find "id=invoice-method" and then add an extra class like so 
`<div class="radio hide">`

This is the only way because the html is generated automatically.

Comment: And where exactly are you stuck? You must have tried *something*, haven't you?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "find an id which is placed within a div"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `closest` parent that is `div` with class radio instead of `previous` element.

```
$('#invoice-method').parent().addClass("hide");
```

OR

```
$('#invoice-method').closest('div').addClass("hide");
```

Comment: Stupid me... off course I didn't thought "closest". Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#invoice-method').parent().addClass('hide');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#invoice-method').closest('div')...
```

Comment: Can you please expand on this?

Comment: `$('#invoice-method')` finds the element by id. `closest('div')` finds the closest ancestor that is a div.